# jVisualVM catalog not working after updating to Java 7 update 21

Tags: java, java-7, visualvm, jvisualvm

I'm on OSX Mountain Lion. If I run `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm` and attempt to goto to the plugins menu, I get the following error:

> Unable to connect to the Java VisualVM Plugins Center because of Zero
>   sized file reported at
>   http://visualvm.java.net/uc/7u6/updates.xml.gz?unique=09e849fb5-7648-4061-afd4-0d05e6204bcc_c07afee2-a35a-4d84-9a69-8a55d0026c19

What the heck is going on?

Comment: Ah nuts, anyone? I'm sure this isn't affecting just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, the java.net migration broke it: https://java.net/projects/visualvm/lists/users/archive/2013-04/message/1